# unsure about query result

Tags: php, mysql

i have this working query

```
Sum(`sales`.`quantity`) AS totquantity,
`transactions`.`price` AS price,
Sum(`sales`.`quantity`)  *  `transactions`.`price` AS grantot
from (`sales` join `transactions` on((`transactions`.`idtransaction` = `sales`.`idtransaction`)))
where ((`sales`.`createon` > '01/01/2017') and (`sales`.`createon` < 'now()'))
group by `sales`.`idtransaction`
```

but it would be usefully to consult to create this view

```
     select `products`.`idproduct` AS `idproduct`,`transactions`.`idtransaction` AS 
`idtransaction`,`transactions`.`idline` AS `idline`,
    `products`.`name` AS `name`,`products`.`code` AS `code`,`transactions`.`price` AS `price`,`sales`.`quantity` AS `quantity`,`sales`.`createon` AS `createon` 
    from (`sales` left join (`transactions` left join `products` on((`products`.`idproduct` = `transactions`.`idproduct`))) on((`transactions`.`idtransaction` = `sales`.`idtransaction`)))
```

and make a query on the view like

```
select * from myview where `sales`.`createon` > '01/01/2017' and `sales`.`createon` < 'now()'
```

now my question is are the two result the same?

thx in advance

Comment: try it and check it

Comment: You can't run them both and compare the results yourself?

Comment: It'd be quicker to run a test than to to ask here, surely, especially if you already have test data. Also this seemingly has nothing to do with PHP, so not sure why you tagged that.

Comment: well with just few data it work, but my question i relative to a big amount of it. it's hard to simulate all situations. example here is a bit simplified..

Answer (score 1):

Your original query uses two tables and full joins.

However, the view has already three tables and left joins.

That’s enough to conclude there is no guarantee they produce the same result in general.

You can provide more precise inputs to get more precise answer.